# 1D transmission lines wave equation solution

Tags: waves, wavefunction

you may know that the solution of 1D wave equation by  d’Alembert is F(x-ct)+F(x+ct) and my question is that like is this F(x-ct) at transmission lines only the equation of one forward going wave that we sketch in the zigzag diagram or is it the sum of all the forward going waves?and the same question for F(x+ct)!
I hope it doesn't need furthermore clarification.
thanks allot